# Is the result of strcmp the same on all machines and compilers?

Tags: c

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   
    int n = strcmp("hello","help");
    printf("%d\n", n ) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
-1
```

Does the value for this program have to be the same on all machines or different compilers?

In other words can this return value take on different values for the same program when run on different compilers or different machines?

Comment: Yes. Why do you suspect otherwise?

Comment: @MichaelT I, at least, have heard that the only requirements for `strcmp` is that it returns negative, zero, and positive - but the particulars are up to implementation.  (That is, it could be as simple as -1, 0, and 1, or the magnitudes could be some measure of difference between the strings)

Comment: @Izkata my apologies for the ambiguity - there are two question marks in the question, and they have opposite answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, only its sign is specified.

C99 §7.21.4.2 The `strcmp` function

Synopsis:

```
#include <string.h>
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Description:

The `strcmp` function compares the string pointed to by `s1` to the string pointed to by `s2`.

The `strcmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero,
accordingly as the string pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`.

Comment: Is the meaning of "greater than" specified? Could "AA" > "Z" because the length is bigger, for example?

Comment: It's specified elsewhere that the comparison is between the first non-equal characters in the string, yes.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ "A" > "Z" could be true if an unusual character encoding was used.  (non-ASCII)  Otherwise with ASCII, both  "AB" > "Z"  and  "A" > "Z"  are false as 'A' < 'Z'.